# Products get unassigned from category once in a while

Tags: catalog, category, magento-1.6

as the title says, I'm having a problem that's repeating from time to time and I don't know the final solution to avoid happening it again.
I have lots of products assigned to certain categories under one main root category. But from time to time, they just dissapear by getting unassigned.

My reassigned them 2 times already but now is treading on my nerves!

What might be the problem? Where should I look ?

Another thing that may help someone give me a proper diagnostic: when I assing products, I assign them only to the subcategories, I never check the root category when I add a new product.

Still, some products remained assigned even though they are included only in a subcategory.

Any clues would do much good.

Thanks.

Comment: Couple of questions for more information.
- Are you using flat catalogs? (System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend > Use flat catalog categories: yes)
- Does the disappearance coincide with the reindexing?
- How many products / categories do you have anyway?
- Are you running any product imports or other automated tasks
- Could you maybe list the 3th party extensions you have installed?

Comment: Well, I'm not using flat catalogs. They're set to 'no'. And I'm not sure if the dissapearance coincides with reindexing, I would say not necessarily. I have only 4-5 categories, but I use only 2.

Comment: In that case it doesn't have to do with reindexing. That's at least one possible cause down. Any scripts/ imports or 3th party extensions that might be causing it?

Comment: I'm not sure. I've installed many extensions, but smaller ones that don't have anything to do with categories.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you without more specific info. I'd either look at Extensions that might cause the issue, automated tasks or it might be that your shop is too large (~500.000+ products)

Answer (score 3):

How many products do you have in a category? If there is more than 1000 then the problem may be with php [max-input-vars](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) settings. Php allows by default only 1000 vars from form to be sent. Every element above 1000 is being dropped. So if you save a category that has for example 1100 products assigned you are probably to lost 100 of them. To test that, go to the category and save it.